# Zero-pad hour in DateFormat

Tags: java, time, date-format, hour

I am trying to display a time difference into a string which follows the form 00:00:00 (hours:minutes:seconds), zero-padded. I have the following code:

```
long timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartRecordingTime;
time = DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss", timeDiff).toString();
```

I was testing it when the timeDiff was no more than a few seconds but the hour does not show as 00. I am in the JST timezone by the way.

Comment: The actual problem was the hour would show as 09, not 00.

Comment: Instead of showing elapsed time as a time-of-day (ambiguous and confusing), use the standard [ISO 8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` such as `PT4S` for four seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get mStartRecordingTime?  It doesn't look to me like it was set with System.currentTimeMillis() in the same locale; if it had been, then the time difference would have reflected the actual difference and this would have worked.  It appears that the recording time somehow got set with UTC, 9 hours away from JST.

The other poster is correct, a date produced with this value would be near epoch, but if you're just trying to get hours, minutes, and seconds, then you should be all right. Keep in mind that you're dealing with elapsed time, not clock/calendar time, so I wouldn't expect the date formatting (as opposed to time formatting) things to work for you.

Comment: I set it from another class using:

    mRecorder.mStartRecordingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
long timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartRecordingTime;
String time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date(timeDiff));
```

Comment: careful there, timeDiff will only be a few seconds, so new Date(timeDiff) will give you a date sometime in 1970

Answer (score 0):

You need to compensate for the time zone.  With what you have, it is probably easiest to change the date formatter to use UTC as the time zone.  Here is some code that should help:

```
    long timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartRecordingTime;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String time = df.format(new Date(timeDiff));
```

Note the change to 'HH' is the date format to display times in a 24 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between( 
    LocalTime.of( 12 , 5 , 0 ) ,
    LocalTime.of( 12 , 7 , 0 ) 
).toString()
```

> PT2M

If, against my strong recommendation to use `Duration`, you insist on using ambiguous/confusing time-of-day formatting:

```
LocalTime.MIN.plus(
    Duration.between( 
        LocalTime.of( 12 , 5 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 12 , 7 , 0 ) 
    )
).toString();
```

> 00:02

To force all three components (hours, minutes, seconds), use the predefined [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME).

```
LocalTime.MIN.plus(
    Duration.between( 
        LocalTime.of( 12 , 5 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 12 , 7 , 0 ) 
    )
).format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME )
```

> 00:02:00

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/fRQmOr).

## Moment != span-of-time

Do not abuse a date-time class such as `java.util.Date` to store elapsed time. Such a class represents a moment, not a span of time.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Do not use troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`. Those are now supplanted by java.time classes.

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

Get the current moment.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Simulate a later time.

```
Instant future = now.plus( Duration.ofMinutes( 5 ) );
```

## `Duration`

Capture elapsed time with a [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) or `Period` object. Each of these represent a span of time, the first handles days-hours-minutes-seconds and the second handles years-months-days.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( now , future );
```

## String format

To present that duration value as a String, do not use time-of-day formatting as that is ambiguous. Instead use standard [ISO 8601 format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). This format, `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`, marks the beginning with a `P`. The `T` in the middle separates the years-months-days portion from the hours-minutes-seconds portion. For example, two and a half hours is `PT2H30M`. Our example here of five minutes is `PT5M`.

```
String output = duration.toString();  // PT5M
```

## `LocalTime`

If you do have an actual time-of-day and want to format with padding zeros, use the default format of [`LocalTime::toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#toString--).

```
LocalTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toString();  // 02:03:04.789Z
```

Another example. Again, I do *not* recommend abusing `LocalTime` this way. (Instead, stick with `Duration` for elapsed time.)

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
LocalTime stop = start.plusMinutes( 7 );
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
LocalTime result = LocalTime.MIN.plus( d );  // I do *not* recommend abusing `LocalTime` this way. Use `Duration` instead for elapsed time.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME ;
String output = result.format( f );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

> output: 00:07:00

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/fRQmOr).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).